# Formula for sizing an induction suppression capacitor

Tags: capacitor, induction

I’m using a set of 12vdc  wireless relays to control a 12vdc solenoid and a 120vac, 1.6 amp motor.
The relay manufacturer recommends an induction suppression capacitor to protect the control electronics.
I’m looking for the formula and / or guidelines to size the capacitors correctly.
I’ve been looking around the net but haven’t found anything that’s clear to me.

Edited to respond to comments.
This is the relay assembly [Relay Pros 4 Channel Wireless](https://relaypros.com/Relay/Relay/CAT_RELAY4_KEY_FOB)
They do offer capacitors for induction suppression, but the selection is based only on voltage. I have a better chance of meeting the deadline if I can source the parts locally (this is being used for a prop in a television series that I work on in special effects).
So, I was asking for guidelines or a formula that I can use to plug in my known values so I can get the correct capacitor and avoid possible induction problems with the relays and microcontroller.

Comment: Who is the relay manufacturer and what specific relay are we discussing? And why doesn't the manufacturer provide a suggestion? Do they just make vague recommendations for their own parts and then fail to provide any specifics to help their customers be successful with their products? (And if a capacitor, you may also need a dissipating resistor though the details of the relay may change that thought, too.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.omron.com.au/service_support/FAQ/FAQ02804/index.asp  OMRON were the best suppliers of contact relays for reliability. Now they specialize in solid-state.

Heed their advice de-ratings as max and add margin.

When contacts close on a capacitor, the ESR of the Cap determines the initial surge current and if there is contact bounce, this causes a 5000'K arc in air which gradually wears out the silver content,

When contacts open with dry contacts dI/dt is extremely high, and the motor current creates a bigger arc than the small Mylar Cap. But this is a tradeoff to choose the right size.  Exceed the nominal peak voltage by at least 50~100% and add a series R to limit contact closure current.

Use the following as guides for C and R
values:

C: 0.5 to 1 μF per 1 A of contact current (A)
R: 0.5 to 1 Ω per 1 V of contact voltage (V)

Ref:

https://www.omron.com.au/service_support/FAQ/FAQ02804/index.asp

Comment: The above link is broken.  I believe this is the new link:  https://www.ia.omron.com/support/faq/answer/36/faq02804/